# Expo listen for browser dismiss

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo

In my expo react native app, the user is directed to a URL in a [WebBrowser](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser/#webbrowserdismissbrowser). I would like to be able to listen for when the user closes/ dismisses the WebBrowser and then execute a function. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using an [authentication session](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser/#webbrowseropenauthsessionasyncurl-redirecturl) (`openAuthSessionAsync`) instead of a standard web browser (`openBrowserAsync`). With an auth session a promise is returned and every second the system checks whether the window has been closed by the user. If it has been then that promise will resolve with `{ type: 'cancel' }`.

Answer (score 1):

With openBrowserAsync :

```js
const resp = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(url);
if (resp && resp.type === "cancel") {
  console.log('Browser closed by user');
}
```